# 3-part routing for web application

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently developing a web app and got stuck while determining htaccess rule for routing requests.

I'd like to have something like this (m=module, a=action, o=object of action):

```
www.domain.com/m/a/o
```

For general requests I plan to have this (o is empty):

```
www.domain.com/users/login
to: www.domain.com/index.php?m=users&a=login
www.domain.com/users/logout
to: www.domain.com/index.php?m=users&a=logout
```

But for site-wide routing I'd like:

```
www.domain.com/projects/show/123
to: www.domain.com/index.php?m=projects&action=show&object=123
```

Generally speaking, there is a rule for which I'd like to set my .htaccess for redirection as follows:

```
www.domain.com/EMPTY 
    to: www.domain.com?index.php
www.domain.com/([^-]a-z0-9) 
    to: www.domain.com?index.php?m=$1
www.domain.com/([^-]a-z0-9)/([^-]a-z0-9) 
    to: www.domain.com?index.php?m=$1&a=$2
www.domain.com/([^-]a-z0-9)/([^-]a-z0-9)/([^-]a-z0-9) 
    to: www.domain.com?index.php?m=$1&a=$2&o=$3
```

Can you help with this?

I've tried something like this but failed for anything longer than the domain itself:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^-]a-z0-9+)$ index.php?m=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^-]a-z0-9+)/([^-]a-z0-9+)$ index.php?m=$1&a=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^-]a-z0-9+)/([^-]a-z0-9+)/([^-]a-z0-9+)$ index.php?m=$1&a=$2&o=$3 [L]
```

Comment: You're doing it horribly wrong. If you want your `mod_rewrite` to be flexible, you need to implement a Front Controller and then just add Simple Rule for all requests, like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]`. <- This is how Zend2 and Symfony2 do it

Comment: Do you mean exploding REQUEST_URI ?

Comment: 1) You need a Router (That determines if there is a match in request URI) 2) A Dispatcher (That build instances according to route match). No, exploding isn't efficient here, because an URI may contain variables too. Say it could be `/article/(:id)`. The only efficient way of doing it is regular expressions, not `explode()`

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I've tried this in the first place, but obviously I did something wrong. Thanks for help.

Comment: And also, you cannot do that correctly without MVC/MVP structure.